# Return value in a called method

Tags: php, oop, laravel-5.1

I know it's a trivial question, but could somebody explain to me why does the return view('some.view'); not get executed? Instead, the return redirect does.

I'm using Laravel 5.1.

In a controller i got two methods:

```
public function change(Request $request){

    if($request->edit === 'Edit')
    {
        $this->edit($request);
    }
    return redirect('to-route');
}

public function edit(Request $request){
    return view('some.view');
}
```

I understand that the edit() method should execute and then it continue his work in the change() method, but why does it ignore the return?

Comment: does `$request->edit === 'Edit'` if not so it might not execute that function

Comment: dadin84 explained the solution. And yea, that statement gives true, it just ignored the return from the called method. Still thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Your `change()` function you are calling the method `$this->edit($request);` however the return value is not being used by your script. If you would like to use the return value;

```
$editReturn = $this->edit($request);
```

Then you can use this variable to show what returned. If you want to return the result from `edit()` also as the return value from `change()` you can just do;

```
return $this->edit($request);
```

inside your `change()` function. However this will mean that your existing return is not executed.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that the return in the second method will be enough. Now i just added return to the call.

Comment: Glad it helped you, happy coding ;)